# ObjectGears inherited column with the same code - use in scripts

Tags: objectgears

If I have two Objectgears classes when the second one inherits from the first one, can I have in both the classes a column with the same code? How will be these properties used in scripts? How shall I refer to two columns of the same class with the same code (one inherited, one owned directly by the class)?

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness is required within a single class, however, the class from which you inherit may have column of the same code. When accessing the column from a script you distinguish:
1) If the column is from the class, for which the record is read, then use a normal access: dr['column_code'] = ...
2) if the column is from a parent class, use adapted access: dr['parent_class_code.column_code'] = ...